# Python - How to receive WMI events asynchronously

Tags: python, asynchronous, events, wmi

I want to receive WMI events asynchronously and handle them with a SWbemSink object. [Microsoft instructs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393877(v=vs.85).aspx) to call IWbemServices.ExecNotificationQueryAsync passing it a SWbemSink instance. When an event occurs it is delivered to the OnObjectReady method of the SWbemSink object so that the client can handle it. Below is an example of how to do this in js. How can we do this in Python? I know how to interact with WMI using win32com.client but how can a Python script be implemented so that it executes in this event-driven fashion?

```
//Connects to default namespace (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\WBEM\Scripting\Default Namespace).
var wbemServices = GetObject("WinMgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(security)}"); 

//Create an event sink object.
var sink = WScript.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemSink", "SINK_");

//Register an event query describing which events the client would like
//to receive.
wbemServices.ExecNotificationQueryAsync(
    sink, "Select * From __InstanceOperationEvent within 0.5 Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' and TargetInstance.Caption='explorer.exe'");

//Show a msg box to allow user to stop receiving events.    
var wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
wshShell.Popup("Click OK to stop listening for events...");
sink.Cancel();


//SWbemSink function called every time an event is ready.
function SINK_OnObjectReady(wbemObject, asyncContext) {
    WScript.Echo("Event received: " + wbemObject.GetObjectText_());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

Use wmi.WMI.watch_for(). See [wmi – Windows Management Instrumentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/wmi.html)

Comment: How is this asynchronous?

Comment: watch_for() is not asynchronous (nor I said it was) but you can make so by running it in its own thread.